# Why are the zero modes of the below operator Killing vectors? (2+1 dimensional gravity)

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, quantum-gravity

I'm trying to understand the eigenmodes of the following operator:

$$(\Delta_{(1)}^{L L}-\frac{2}{3} R)V_\nu \equiv -\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu V_\nu+R_{\nu \mu} V^\mu  -\frac{2}{3} RV_\nu $$

Where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci curvature tensor and working in 2+1 dimensional gravity with a Euclidean signature. Using $R_{\mu \nu}=\frac{R}{3} g_{\mu \nu}$ I have shown that this is the same as $-\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu V_\nu-R_{\mu \nu} V^\mu$. The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4620) I'm reading states that this implies that the zero modes of this operator are Killing vectors, i.e. when this equation is zero $\nabla_{(\mu} V_{\nu)}=0$. The paper also states that for spherical three manifolds ($S^3$ and Lens spaces), it is clear that this operator has no negative modes. Unfortunately, I am unable to see either of these statements. I would appreciate it greatly if somebody could point out why this is the case. Thanks in advance!